# How can I debug EF returned data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have built an internal app to allow users to see orders pending from our website. 99.9% of the time there are no problems, however a few times a day I get the error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null.

I'm using a timer to execute the following code and then WebSockets sends it to the clients:

```
var _orders = db.Orders.Where(o =>
        !(o.Cancelled ?? false)
        && (o.EvoImport == null || !o.EvoImport.Imported || (o.OrdersChanged.Any() && o.EvoAmendImport != null && !o.EvoAmendImport.Imported) || (o.OrderPrintings.Any() && o.OrderPrintings.Max(p => p.PrintDate) < o.OrderDate))
        && !unpaid.Contains(o.Paid)).GroupJoin(db.CustomerOrders, o => o.BasketID, c => c.BasketID, (o, c) => new { Order = o, Customers = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
    .SelectMany(d => d.Customers.Select(c => new { Order = d.Order, Customer = c })).Take(100);

orders.AddRange(_orders
    .Select(o =>
        new OrderLine()
        {
            Amendment = (bool?)o.Order.OrdersChanged.Any() ?? false,
            BasketID = o.Order.BasketID ?? -1,
            Company = o.Customer.AccountCode,
            Completed = o.Order.Complete ?? false,
            DeliveryDate = o.Order.CustomerDelivery.FirstOrDefault().EvoDispatchDate.Value,
            EmailID = o.Order.OrderEmails.OrderByDescending(e => e.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault().EmailID,
            JobNumber = o.Order.JobNumber,
            OrderDate = o.Order.OrderDate,
            OrderID = o.Order.OrderID,
            OrderRef = o.Order.OrderID,
            Payment = o.Order.Paid,
            Reprinting = (bool?)(!o.Order.OrderPrintings.Any() || o.Order.OrderPrintings.Max(p => p.PrintDate) < o.Order.OrderDate) ?? false,
            Type = o.Order.Door == null ? "Null Door" : o.Order.Door.FireDoor ?? false ? "Fire Door" : "Door Set"
        }));
```

I've separated the iQueryable out to try and help me debug this but it hasn't helped. Now, like I said above, I get the error maybe 4 - 5 times a day, and this runs every ten seconds, for the most part just fine.

FYI: The fields Amendment, Completed and Reprinting are the only booleans.

What I am trying to find out is what is coming back as null from SQL when it should be a boolean. The debugger stops on the whole AddRange block, to the end of the code shown. If SQL profiler could just show me the returned data I'd be happy.

What I've tried:

- dynamic object assignment instead of new OrderLine; This results is the same error
- ForEach loop instead of add range; This appears to have stopped the error, but it's calling SQL for each-and-every line, this is a performance hit I don't think I should need. Plus I have no idea if I didn't just leave it debugging for long enough.
- ToList() the iQueryable; This just shifts the error to a Int32 instead of a Boolean, and it occurs on the var _orders declaration. But I still can't see the returned data.
- Inspecting the SQL command sent, this all looks like it should return booleans to me. I can add it (it's quite lengthy) if anyone wants to see it.

All I'm trying to do here is work out which cast is failing, if I could see the returned data when there's an error then I'd be a happy bunny, but my Google foo is failing to return any useful answers on how to do that. Inspection of the _orders causes an enumeration of the results and SQL passes back a fresh set of data and this time it's all good. If I hit F5 and continue, it carries on just fine. I could just stick a loop round this and keep trying till it works but that just seems wrong to me.

**EDIT**
Here is the OrderLine class as requested:

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public bool Amendment { get; set; }
    public int BasketID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string DSNumber => $"DS{(JobNumber ?? "").PadLeft(7, '0')}";
    public int? EmailID { get; set; }
    public int EmailType => Type == "Prepped Slab" ? 2 : 1;
    public string FriendlyDate => OrderDate.HasValue ? OrderDate.Value.FriendlyDate() : "";
    public string FriendlyDeliveryDate => DeliveryDate?.ToShortDateString() ?? "";
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderIdentifier => $"{Type},{OrderID},{BasketID}";
    [Display(Name = "View")]
    [Link(Target = "doorvault")]
    public string OrderPrintURL => $"/Order/ViewEmail/{BasketID}?type={EmailType}&orderid={OrderID}";
    public int OrderRef { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public bool Reprinting { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool ViewEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your database table schemas (columns, datatypes and null/not null; screenshot is enough) and your class definitions for type `Order`.

Comment: I've added the OrderLine class, the database schema is pages and pages of code, probably best not shared publicly and I don't see how it would help. The code works most of the time, if you were to try and debug this for me you'd need all the code relating to how a customer get an order in the orders table, which I can't share publicly either. Whilst it would be brilliant if you could tell me what to change and what to change it to, all I really need is a little pointer to how I can identify the Cast failure, or why EF does this in the first place.

Comment: Check the associated database table. Which of the fields are nullable? Which of those have NULL entries? Can you consistently reproduce the error with one of these entries?